# Amazon Lightsail ssl verification without using domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-lightsail

We are using amazon lightsail, but we could not approve our ssl certificate. We are using Node js and we do not have a domain name, we only connect by ip. It still keeps saying insecure when we use ssl certificate. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

> It still keeps saying insecure when we use ssl certificate

Any browser will say that. You **must have** your own domain and proper SSL certificate for that. Without the domain, no modern browser, or even https client, will allow connections without at least a warning.